# How to see the TLS cipher of an openldap connection?

Tags: ssl, openldap

Our OpenLDAP Servers run version on EL6. OpenLDAP is built against the Mozilla Network Security Services (NSS) libraries. Our LDAP clients come from a wide variety of Unix & Linux systems.

We are unable to get OpenLDAP connections working for clients or replication when we use our preferred TLS ciphers.

For example, if we use Red Hat's [Strongest available ciphers only](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1475953) list, such as this:

```
# /etc/openldap/slapd.conf
TLSProtocolMin 3.2
TLSCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:!RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!EDH:!EXP:!SSLV2:!eNULL
```

Client connections fail, because they do not meet our ACL requirement for a minimum Security Strength Factor (SSF):

```
slapd[22887]: conn=1022 fd=20 ACCEPT from IP=192.168.100.101:35936 (IP=192.168.100.100:636)
slapd[22887]: conn=1022 fd=20 TLS established tls_ssf=128 ssf=128
...
slapd[22887]: <= check a_authz.sai_ssf: ACL 256 > OP 128
```

How can I see which cipher is being used for this connection so that I can eliminate it from the list?

If we disable the cipher list and use the defaults provided by OpenLDAP + NSS, it works:

```
# /etc/openldap/slapd.conf
TLSProtocolMin 3.2
# TLSCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:!RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!EDH:!EXP:!SSLV2:!eNULL


slapd[6020]: conn=1003 fd=20 ACCEPT from IP=192.168.100.101:35936 (IP=192.168.100.100:636)
slapd[6020]: conn=1003 fd=20 TLS established tls_ssf=256 ssf=256
```

However, the default list is unacceptable because it includes some weak ciphers which our security team doesn't want, such as RC4-SHA & RC4-MD5 ciphers.

We are aware that EL6 is becoming EOL by the end of the year. That's a different problem.

Comment: (1) wireshark or tshark, or if not available/authorized either `tcpdump -x port 636` (probably also `-n`, maybe `-i`) and look in server first flight at 0x70 (assuming no extensions in the TCP header) for 2, or `tcpdump -wfile port 636` and move the file to somewhere you _do_ have wireshark/tshark (2) I don't know exactly how the OpenSSL-NSS translation works, but in OpenSSL `DEFAULT:!RC4` would do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing. Of all things, I had to disable AES_128 using `!AES128`. RC4, MD5, etc. were already disabled by the OS, apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to do this directly with `tcpdump` or `tshark` on the node. What I had to do was to capture `tcpdump` on the machine, transfer the data to my laptop and then run a modern version of Wireshark per https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52150/identify-ssl-version-and-cipher-suite

Another very helpful command was to use `nmap`'s scripts to enumerate the ciphers:

```
$ nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 636 ldap.example.org -Pn


PORT    STATE SERVICE
636/tcp open  ldapssl
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
...
|   TLSv1.2
|     Ciphers (16)
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA


Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.34 seconds
```

Those `AES_128` ciphers are causing my problem, and so I disabled them by adding it to the list of excluded ciphers:

```
TLSCipherSuite HIGH:!LOW:!MEDIUM:!RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!EDH:!EXP:!SSLV2:!eNULL:!AES128
```